Make sure an object with a particular key is statically created once
I'd like to implement the following in C#:

A class with a property of Key which will be used to uniquely identify an object
A set of pre-defined static objects

using System.Text.Json;

public sealed class Test
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> _existingKeys = [];

    public static readonly Test One = new("one");
    public static readonly Test Two = new("two");

    public Test(string key)
    {
        if (!_existingKeys.Add(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Key '{key}' is already in use.");
        }

        Key = key;
    }

    public string Key { get; }
}

// Example usage
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var three = new Test("one");
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Output: Key 'one' is already in use.
        }

        var one = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Test.One);
        try
        {
            var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(one);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Output: Key 'one' is already in use.
        }
    }
}

The issue I'm facing is deserialization because it attempts to instantiate an object that may already exist in memory. Is there a workaround to this? I'd like to avoid manually maintaining the key map because some classes will have a lot of pre-defined objects and it's easy to miss an object. Additionally, there are use cases where the objects need to be defined outside the definition class in another assembly.
Note that I only care about uniqueness for user-defined objects.
public static readonly Test One = new("one");

Things like deserialization / reflection are outside the scope.

What is the expected result of deserializing an existing key?

And why did you say "because some classes will have a lot of pre-defined objects"? Does the class have just one key property?

It should deserialize without an exception. One key property. For example, there will be a base class with that property and many derived classes whose objects all need to be uniquely identified by key.

How will you uniquely identify them? If you just want to get equal results when comparing two objects with the same key, you can refer to the remarks of the GetHashCode method. If you strictly require that each key to correspond to only one object, then write a custom converter for the type.

Assuming that the Test class is a minimal example, will the 'real' classes have other properties than Key?

They will have other properties, but only Key should define uniqueness.

This looks like a variation of the Flyweight pattern, so you may want to edit the class so that it instead looks like this:
[JsonConverter(typeof(TestJsonConverter))]
public sealed class Test
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Test> _existingObjects = new();

    public static readonly Test One = Create("one");
    public static readonly Test Two = Create("two");

    private Test(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public static Test Create(string key)
    {
        if (_existingObjects.TryGetValue(key, out var existing))
            return existing;

        var newObject = new Test(key);
        _existingObjects[key] = newObject;
        return newObject;
    }

    public string Key { get; }
}

Notice that the constructor is now private, so that all client code instead has to use the Create function. The static fields One and Two also do this.
Instead of maintaining a set of known IDs, it instead maintains a hashmap of known objects.
Creating a new object by key now never fails, but instead just looks in the hashmap after known objects.
JSON serialization is the tricky part, but as the comment by shingo suggests you can use a custom converter:
internal class TestJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Test>
{
    public override Test? Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var key = reader.GetString();
        if (key is null)
            return null;
        return Test.Create(key);
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        Test value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.Key);
    }
}

This one is just a proof of concept, and you may want to modify it according to your particular requirements.
These tests now pass:
[Fact]
public void CreateOneByKey()
{
    var actual = Test.Create("one");
    Assert.Equal(Test.One, actual);
}

[Fact]
public void RoundTripOne()
{
    var one = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Test.One);
    var actual = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(one);
    Assert.Equal(Test.One, actual);
}


public static Test Create(string key) => (CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(_existingObjects, key, out _) ??= new Test(key)); is shorter and a bit faster.

Having this simple class:
public class KeyedClass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

I would define factory class which I would use in custom JsonConverter:
public static class KeyedClassFactory
{
    public const string UniqueKey = "unique key";
    private static readonly KeyedClass _uniqueObject = new KeyedClass() { Key = UniqueKey };

    public static KeyedClass Get(string key)
    {
        return key == UniqueKey
            ? _uniqueObject
            : new KeyedClass { Key = key };
    }
}

Then implement custom JsonConverter:
class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<KeyedClass>
{
    public override KeyedClass? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Of course, you could implement it differently,
        // by reading JSON tokens until you get the value
        // for a Key property, but this is just a shortcut 
        // to achieve this.
        var actualObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<KeyedClass>(ref reader);
        return KeyedClassFactory.Get(actualObject.Key);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, KeyedClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

And usage and the test:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new MyJsonConverter());
    
var o1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<KeyedClass>(
    @"{ ""Key"": ""unique key"" }",
    options);

var o2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<KeyedClass>(
    @"{ ""Key"": ""unique key"" }",
    options);

var o3 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<KeyedClass>(
    @"{ ""Key"": ""unique key blah"" }",
    options);

// Check if we have the same objects:
Console.WriteLine(o1 == o2); // true
Console.WriteLine(o1 == o3); // false

Of course, overall structure of classes and implementation details are up to you :)
